# Replace Null values with values from the same column by matching values in a different column

Tags: mysql, null

I have a table with some null values in column "date":

```
platform   date         id
---------------------------
web        2018-10-10   1
mob                     1
mob                     1
web        2018-10-15   2
mob                     2
ntl        2018-10-09   3
web        2018-10-12   3
web        2018-10-11   4
mob                     3
```

I want to update null values in 'date' for 'mob' platform by matching the 'id' column from platform 'web'. The result should look like this:

```
platform   date         id
---------------------------
web        2018-10-10   1
mob        2018-10-10   1
mob        2018-10-10   1
web        2018-10-15   2
mob        2018-10-15   2
ntl        2018-10-09   3
web        2018-10-12   3
web        2018-10-11   4
mob        2018-10-12   3
```

Will really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE `table` t1, `table` t2
SET t1.`date` = t2.`date`
WHERE t1.id = t2.id
  AND t1.platform = 'mob'
  AND t2.platform = 'web'
  AND t1.`date` IS NULL
  AND t2.`date` IS NOT NULL
```

PS. The solution assumes that in a subarray of the table which matched `` platform = 'web' AND t2.`date` IS NOT NULL `` condition the `id` value is unique. If not, a random value from possible values list will be used, and you must use a subquery instead of `t2` table copy, which filters data by `platform = 'web'` condition, groups it by `id` and selects alone `data` value (maximal, for example) for each `id` value. If your MySQL version is 8+, you may do it in WITH clause.